# How does rstan store posterior samples for separate chains?

Tags: output, stan, rstan

I would like to understand how the output of `extract` in `rstan` orders the posterior samples. I understand that I can view the posterior samples from each chain by using `as.array`,

```
stanfit <- sampling(
  model,
  data = stan.data)
​
fitarray <- as.array(stanfit)
```

For example, `fitarray[, 2, 1]` will give me the samples for the second chain of the first parameter. One way to store the posterior samples in the output of `extract` would be just to concatenate them. When I do,

```
fit <- extract(stanfit)
mean(fitarray[,2,1]) == mean(fit$ss[1001:2000])
```

for several chains and parameters I always get `TRUE` (`ss` is the first parameter). This makes it seem like the posterior samples are being concatenated in `fit`. However, when I do,

```
fitarray[,2,1] == fit$ss[1001:2000]
```

I get `FALSE` (confirmed that there's not just precision difference). It appears that `fitarray` and `fit` are storing the iterations differently. How do I view the iterations (in order) of each posterior sample chain separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from `rstan:::as.array.stanfit`, the `as.array` method is essentially defined as

```
extract(x, permuted = FALSE, inc_warmup = FALSE)
```

Your default use of `extract` keeps the warmup and permutes the post-warmup draws randomly, which is why the indices do not line up with the `as.array` output.